# How to incorporate covariates in a Pareto/NBD model in R/Python?

Tags: python, r

How do you create a Pareto/NBD model for measuring CLV(customer lifetime value) in R/Python **which includes the effect of time-invariant covariates?**

I have so far used `BYTD` package in R and `lifetimes` module in Python to create a Pareto/NBD model but have only been able to use transactions data. The documentation for these packages doesn't specify a way to include covariates.

Comment: Have a look at [this pydata talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gx6oHqpRgpY). It addresses most of your points

Comment: VinceP should be the answer

Comment: For anyone coming across this still, they don't actually talk about incorporating covariates into the model in the talk, but they do point to this paper (https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/mksc.1090.0502) which apparently talks about it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a R package called CLVTools that allows to include time-invariant and time-varying (also called time-dependent) covariates for the Pareto/NBD model : https://cran.r-project.org/package=CLVTools

Here is a step-by-step walk-through based on data from an apparel retailer: https://www.clvtools.com/articles/CLVTools.html

The original paper that introduces the approach is accessible here: https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mksc.2020.1254